Jib Gradle plugin module path v class path?
How does the Job Gradle plugin decide whether to place a particular JAR dependency to the -module-path vs -classpath when running  the java executable. Can this be explicitly controlled/specified?

task.classpath should be the right variable to store the classPath. During execution, gradle automatically uses module-path or classPath.
